# I can't select a child element of area when I create a task (TFS2015)

Tags: tfs

I can't select a child element of area when I create a task. I see only the root element. When I create a bug, I can select a child element of the area.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could other work item types could select the child area at team level? If other work item types could see child areas, you'd better check that if there's any rules under the area path field of Task. In addition, at the XXX.XXX.XX.X:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/POS/teamPOS/_admin/_areas page, check if the child areas is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your team owns the area(s).

`{collection uri}/{project}/{team}/_admin/_work?_a=areas`

You can find this in team project settings.

Comment: This page does not exist. Only, http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/POS/teamPOS/_admin/

Comment: Is it on-prem? Do you have a Work -> Areas section in the project settings? If not, then just Areas? You may need to make sure the areas are assigned to the team. Or, remove the team from the URL to see all areas you have perms to.